# Blatantly wrong accepted answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, wrong-answers

[ADO.NET DataRow - check for column existence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970985/ado-net-datarow-check-for-column-existance/971151#971151)

The accepted answer is factually incorrect; one can simply call

```
row.Table.Columns.Contains(name);
```

What should be done?

Comment: Man ... that comment was not enough "Never write ... ? true : false" you should have just edited the code.

Comment: Also ... that question has two duplicate answers, @Gaurav and @Wyatt have exactly the same answer, @Wyatt had his first but it is a lot less useful cause it has no code sample. I kind of want to delete @Wyatt's answer cause it really adds nothing, but he was first. The conundrum

Comment: @waffles just delete them and change the accepted answer. Don't worry I won't tell anyone it was you

Comment: @waffles#1: I tend to respect answerers' code (even when wrong or bad).  Maybe I shouldn't.

Comment: @Earlz: Even ♦mods cannot force acceptance.

Comment: @drchenstern ... chances are slim that I will start messing around with the db just to push my personal agenda, not likely to happen ever.

Comment: @waffles, oh yea, all that red tape. You should make friends with a developer :)

Comment: Surely the `? true : false` doesn't cause any real problems. Why would you call it "blatantly wrong"? It works, doesn't it, silly and superfluous as it may be.

Comment: @TRiGisTimothyRichardGreen: You're seeing the new accepted answer, after the answer this question asked about was deleted.  The original accepted answer, which you can see when you get 10K reputation, was a 20-line monstrosity with a DataReader and a for loop.

Comment: Ah. That makes this conversation somewhat more intelligible.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Your options are:

- Downvote it
- Comment on it and on the question, hope people read your comments.
- Edit away and fix stuff
- Flag it
- Post a question on meta asking for people to downvote it :)*

As a moderator:

- You can delete in extreme cases (e.g.: how do I rotate my photos: accepted answer `format c:`)

Here is a list of similar questions (questions that have accepted negatively scoring answers)

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/903/questions-with-accepted-answers-that-have-a-negative-score

This topic has been covered quite extensively; though I am not sure it is quite resolved. See:

- [What should be done with accepted, yet wrong, answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24322/what-should-be-done-with-accepted-yet-wrong-answers)
- [Wrong answer accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71380/wrong-answer-accepted)
- [How should we act on accepted questions that are actually wrong?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67335/how-should-we-act-on-accepted-questions-that-are-actually-wrong)
- [Are we unfairly advertising wrong answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49675/are-we-unfairly-advertising-wrong-answers)
- [What should we do about questions marked correct that have obviously incorrect answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83/what-should-we-do-about-questions-marked-correct-that-have-obviously-incorrect-an)

<sup>* This is a joke. Meta shouldn't be used to target specific posts or users. For more information, [see this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245262)</sup>

Comment: Can someone modify that query to make it so that questions with accepted answers and a negative score and **few or no upvotes** is shown? Right now most of these are just controversial/subjective answers.

Comment: This is a good example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163834/php-templates-with-php/166958#166958  :)

Comment: here is another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872543/printf-vs-cout-in-c/2872574#2872574 ... there are plenty in that list

Comment: So what do I do in this case, as this answer is accepted, and wrong (at least part of it); moderators are *not* arbiters of correctness.  We should not delete answers because they are blatantly wrong.  Nor should they be flagged if they are blatantly wrong (this is why we have the rejection reason "moderators should not be informed of technical inaccuracies, yada yada").

Comment: @waffles I posted this question asking people to downvote a wrong answer and I got totally nailed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139307/wrong-answer-marked-accepted#comment392673_139307  After following the advice on this answer.  I'd remove the last point "ask people to downvote" - it doesn't go down well.

Comment: _"**hope** people read your comments"_ I would rephrase to something like **["put your _best effort_ to make sure people will read your comments"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/G2Pf9.png "example screen shot showing how 'best effort' may look like:)")**

Comment: I flagged a blatantly wrong answer and a moderator said **declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer**

Comment: Blatantly wrong answers have the potential to damage SO. People come here for right answers. Truly provably wrong ones do no good for anyone (except possibly rep farmers).

Answer (score 17):

Downvote the ​​​​​​​​​​answer?

Comment: Downvote squad... GO!

Comment: Comment angrily :@

Comment: That wasn't actually what I was asking for.  (and 16 downvotes might be a little excessive)

Comment: Actually the new best answer is "post to meta.. and the [problem will take care of itself](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=He82NBjJqf8)."

Comment: Downvoting wrong but popular answers may very well not have much of an effect, because most users who arrive at the question by definition don't quite know how to answer it, and likely can't tell that the most popular answer is in fact wrong, and will upvote it. [Here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579844/how-does-zalgo-text-work).

Answer (score 11):

- Downvote the answer
- Consider editing the answer if you are absolutely certain it's wrong and your information is correct (ie, it's not just a different way of doing it, it will fail completely)
- Add a new answer with the correct information or upvote the correct answer
- Add a comment to the wrong accepted answer with the correction
- Add a comment to the question requesting the OP re-evaluate their choice for accepted answer

Answer (score 7):

(This is mostly a response to waffles.) So, wait... I hate wrong accepted answers as much as the next guy, but I thought that awarding the checkmark was the asker's privilege. If it's going to be "the asker's privilege unless a bunch of people in comments and/or on MSO agree that it's wrong," then where do you draw the line? What if a lot of people complain, but there are people supporting the OP, too?

I'm not against changing truly terrible accepted answer marks, but we should have some sort of system in place for it. Doing it on an ad-hoc basis will eventually cause more problems than it solves.

Also... here's [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148922/swing-component-jframe-visibilty).

Comment: Lol for your another one boils down to "hmm. You seem to be using X IDE, you should use Y IDE. All your programs will work in Y, completely bug free!"

Comment: I assume your response was to "If it is really really really dangerous delete it?". If so, the number of "really"s seems to indicate he means patently insane things, like Q: "How do I do this thing in C?", A: "Just run rm -rf / on the command-line"

Comment: I would not consider this an extreme enough case for deletion ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911536/built-in-types-when-not-to-use/911543#911543 ... though personally I wish it was deleted

Comment: @Pops: The easy place to draw the line is at the point where the accepted answer gets offensive-deleted...

Comment: The question is moot.  Even ♦mods cannot force acceptance.

Answer (score 1):

Post a bounty to attract more attention.  Hopefully this bounty will draw at least one better answer (if one hasn't been contributed yet).

Then award the bounty to a better answer.

*(I haven't made up my mind what I think about this yet; I'm posting this here since it's the solution I've picked up through SE folklore, and I was surprised not to find this option posted here yet.)*

Comment: This is probably what happened here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join/61563009#61563009