# Wrong answer marked accepted

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, accepted-answer, specific-question

This question:

[RESTful URL design for search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207477/restful-url-design-for-search)

Is a great question and has 71 up-votes to boot, but has unfortunately been marked with the wrong answer.  The correct answer quite rightly has 60 up-votes, to the marked answer's 11.

Why can't the community over-rule the person who asked the question in cases like this?

Comment: I feel like downvoting this question because of your suggestion to downvote that question. It is something entirely non-constructive.

Comment: I agree the competing answer should be upvoted though. Maybe one could also leave a comment to the OP and ask them to consider changing the check mark

Comment: OK I have ammended the question to upvote the correct answer and leave a comment.  I was actually following the advice in this question by asking people to downvote: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78438/blatantly-wrong-accepted-answer

Comment: YOU should downvote (or upvote) when you feel it would be appropriate.  No one should ever ask anyone else to vote in any form, however.  Your votes are purely your own and, ideally, should come naturally.  Likewise, accepting an answer is purely voluntary and up to the OP -- you can point out that an answer is wrong, but you shouldn't ask them to change their acceptance.

Comment: Ugh stop downvoting me, and I can't even delete this dumb question

Comment: Hm? You posted a Meta question asking for people to down vote, and now it's bothering you that you're getting down voted?

Comment: BTW, rep on meta is even less meaningful than the usual stuff, so don't fret the downvotes beyond deciding not to do this again. We won't hold it against you.

Comment: @YannisRizos Yeah - in response to this question which advises to do so!!!!!!  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78438/blatantly-wrong-accepted-answer i've now removed the offending comment and they still downvote

Comment: Downvoting the answer is the proper action, if you feel it's incorrect, however asking others to do the same is _not_.

Comment: @Yannis That's not really a reason to downvote this question to oblivion though. The OP was just trying to be helpful. What the heck happened here?

Comment: @DiscountGucciHandbags I can only speak for my downvote, and it was for the first version of the question... -16 does seem excessive though.

Answer (score 24):

The community **has** overruled - they have up-voted the correct answer, so much so that it is has almost 6 times the upvotes.

When a user accepts an answer they indicate that that's the answer that most helped them, not that it is necessarily the correct answer.

Comment: Actually, if the community voice against that answer is strong enough to get it a negative score deletion votes can be cast.