# Difference between a right answer and the accepted answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Blatantly wrong accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78438/blatantly-wrong-accepted-answer)

Say a user asks a question in Stack Overflow and he gets answers, but he chooses the answer which he thinks right, but is actually wrong. I have seen some questions like this when I've searched on SO. I try the solution accepted by the questioner, but it doesn't work. Other answers works well. How should we handle this?

Comment: When asking the question that post didn't popped up, thanks anyway @SulfurizedDemonbobby

Answer (score 1):

OP has the right to accept any answer. For other Stack Overflow users, the only option is to upvote the answers that they think are correct and optionally add comments so that future visitors can learn what is right (or wrong) with the accepted answer compared to other answers posted for that question.