# Question deleted after eight mintues. What did I do wrong?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, deleted-questions

Are people here, who VTD questions, read with understanding questions, that they vote to delete?

I asked [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/245259/189165). It was **deleted within EIGHT minutes**. I went to toilet and when I came back, I wasn't even able to *write a single comment* to explain or clarify.

I understand, everyone reserves right to have own opinion, but I must admit, that reaction from side of this community actually shocked me (eight minutes?). Especially:

- *bluefeet* saying "Coming to meta to ask users to downvote a post, sorry but that gets a -1 from me" -- cool, I just did, what *waffles* told in *highly upvoted answer*; **if it is wrong, fix or edit it; don't punish me for that**!
- *Oded* said: "This is specific to SO, so why post on MSE? 2. Soliciting downvotes on a meta site - that's not what Waffles said, was it?" -- *waffles* wrote an answer on MSE and yes -- *wafflles* **exactly said something like that**, to cite: "Post a question on meta asking for people to downvote it", have you looked at link given by me, before VTD?
- *Bill the Lizard* asking "It already has a score of -2. What do you think is going to happen if people downvote it even more?" -- I must admit, that you surprised me with this comment; what is going to happen? isn't that questions with -10 are grayed out? That was, what I was expecting,
- *Andrew Barber* saying: "The text from waffles you posted was meant as something of a joke, because that's what the person asking the question did. Admittedly, that may not be obvious"; **no, it is absolutely NOT obvious to me**; maybe I'm more stupid than you; a single smiley at the end doesn't actually mean, someone is joking; he/she just can have a good mood, right? And, **no, there isn't even a trace of joking in OP's question to this answer**; where do you see it?

Once again, I understand, that my question could be wrong and that you reserve right to have your own opinion, completely different than mine. But, guys, **give yourself a break**, I didn't wrote a spam or something completely stupid, I simply made something, that someone understood as a joke, while I didn't. **Give me at least some time to react**. Deleting question within **eight mintues**, which doesn't give me any chance to react, is a behavior, that I seen on many very low quality forums and among very low quality communities. I'd never expect  such behavior here and among you.

Sorry, but my general opinion about this community has been *downvoted* about 100 times for past ten mintues. Pity and sad, but true. I know, that you completely don't care about that, but at least I had a chance to express my thoughts. You didn't give me that chances, by deleting question after 8 minutes!

Comment: It's interesting to me that you found my response, which you have quoted faithfully above, to be **shocking**. Really?

Comment: @AndrewBarber Your comment is another example (for me), that you read many posts without understanding. I found entire community response shoking, not your answer.

Comment: *shocking, not shoking please!

Comment: To summarize: I asked, what I did wrong. That's something, because most people would send a "screw you" message instead. Maybe my tone was incorrect. Many people gets worse or better days, right? I wanted to be polite and gently asked, what I did wrong, and in exchange, I've lost nearly 50 rep so far and got some not polite response, like the one (most voted), that I shouldn't go to a toilet (completely pointless and stupid). Maybe you're right, that I was rude, but you're certainly sending a wrong message. I'm not going to ask again, if I do something wrong. It's completely pointless in here.

Comment: Punishing someone, who misunderstood a joke (an apparently bad one), by downvoting their question to oblivion and making fun of them is not what I would call *"Be nice"* (See the new Stack Exchange policy).

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Thank you, Simon, for your support. Unfortunately, you're just the one out of many, who think differently.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you did wrong was, you took a joke seriously. The net result was - nothing at all! Any rep changes as a result of the question were reversed when it was deleted, most people can't see the question, so it's like it never happened.

What could you have done differently? I am sure once you realized that the "post on meta asking for downvotes" suggestion was a joke, that you would have deleted your question anyway. So you had a few moments of discomfort once you realized the truth of the matter, and then it was all over. Right?

Why delete it instead of downvote it? In case users who also didn't realize that's a wrong thing to do were to read it and act on it. You know it shouldn't stick around, I'm sure you do.

Comment: "What happens in Meta-Deleted-Land, stays..." Yeah; I can't finish that!

Comment: Thank you for a very good answer. I agree with everythnig you wrote. The only pity thing is, that "_any rep changes as a result of **this question** (-14 so far) won't be reversed_". -22 rep (so far), for asking, what I did wrong. This leads to a question: what I did wrong with current question, that I was "priced" with -22 rep? But, that sounds like and endless and non-sense loop.

Comment: @trejder You do come off very rant-ish at the end. If you had phrased your question more as a legitimate attempt at figuring out why your question was deleted rather than sounding like someone who's just upset, yelling at the world, and accusing the community of also doing something wrong, it might have been received better.

Comment: People may have better or worse day. I don't know many, who would stand without emotions, if someone said "shut up" and mute them after eight minutes since asking. I could sound rantish (in your opinion) or could not. That doesn't change the fact, that punishing someone, who asks "What I did wrong" is very wrong, no matter, what circumstances for asking are. That is not, how people are dealing things around me. Maybe (probably) this is normal around MSE community. Pity.

Comment: @trejder the rep you lost when the (now-deleted) question was downvoted has come back. It's true you've suffered another loss on this question asking about it (though not from me) but that's probably because of the tone - asking people if they even read things before acting on them tends to set a bad tone to start with and it went downhill from there. The more sure you are that you're right, the less you're actually asking a question, no?

Answer (score 17):

It was a bad question that deserved to be deleted, so it was.

I don't think it's appropriate to use Meta.SE to coordinate votes against a specific Stack Overflow post. Had you posted that to Meta.SO (where it arguably was a better fit), I would have deleted that myself.

Frankly, I don't think any response on your part would have saved that question.

Comment: "_I don't think any response on your part would have saved that question_". If _you_ think, that _other person_ has nothing to say, then the best option is to _mute opponent_, right? But, that sounds a little bit like communism or fundamentalism, don't you think? Ever passed your mind, that you might be wrong, and that I may have something to say? What gives you right, to decide for me and take the right of speaking out of me? I'm just curious.

Comment: @trejder - You missed your chance to call me a Nazi, and round out the trifecta. This isn't a freedom of speech issue, you explicitly called for us to target downvotes at an individual post. Such targeting is frowned upon here, and we do remove Meta posts (even well-meaning ones) that do so.

Answer (score 2):

The "What did I do wrong?" style of question should be better placed in chat, where someone can point you in the direction of the Help links on the site where you think that you did something wrong.

You should only post on the Meta of a site if you have read the Help section and have a good understanding of the type of content that is On-Topic on that site.

This question is a good indicator that you should have asked for help in chat, you have plenty of Rep for that.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with asking this kind of question on meta either. But sure, it could also be asked in chat.